# In SQL Reporting, can you make a Cell Invisible but keep its Borders Visible?

Tags: reporting-services

Otherwise, when rendered in Excel it looks bad to me.

I don't want to format numeric values as blank strings, because then the .xls file's got exclamation points in every cell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS Hiding the textbox in a table cell causes the borders to disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602651/ssrs-hiding-the-textbox-in-a-table-cell-causes-the-borders-to-disappear)

Answer (score 0):

Can you make simply make the text white on white instead?

If `Visible` is false in SSRS then it isn't usually rendered so you can't have borders. There may be some way to "hide" it using a text box inside a rectangle but I'm not sure how that would export.