# SSRS Hiding the textbox in a table cell causes the borders to disappear

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012-datatools

I have a report with a  table in it. And each table cell has borders around it.

The problem I'm experiencing is that if I hide the textbox in any of the cells, the borders also disappear.

I want the textbox to hide but still show the borders.

The textbox in question shows the visibility toggle icons (+/-) so I can't use an iif statement to change the textbox's value to be an empty string when I don't want to see anything in it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can place the textbox inside a rectangle.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. I can't upvote this answer because I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Even if you can't up vote this you should be able to accept this as the answer since you are the one that asked it. :)

Comment: Done. :) Sorry I haven't used StackOverflow too much. I totally overlooked at that part.

Comment: It worked like charm! Thank you for posting simple and great solution.

Answer (score 0):

***So , I was having this same issue:* **

The Problem:

I assume that you placed a border around your text box and decided to place the hide and toggle element to your text box. or your Rows are not stepped down.  Two solutions, I think the first solution is what you are looking for:

Solution 1:

I Noticed that SRSS reporting also has this grouping feature by rows.   So to hide the text in the textbox without losing borders is to create a step-down feature within the grouping.  So basically you can assign hide text box property without disturbing the rows above the textbox.   This may be a better solution.

Solution 2:

You must instead place the border attribute to your text box and place the hide and toggle function on the individual groups.  So for you, you have to remove the hide + toggle feature on the textbox. Right click the group element in your "rows" or "columns" and assign your drilldown  hide + toggle feature on the group elements. In other words: "group properties" not "text box properties"

I hope this re-solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I solved it by changing the text color to white (or whatever the background color of the textbox is). I was doing this inside a table, and couldn't find a way to insert a textbox inside of a rectangle as stated in the other answer...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and used similar approach like @Anony Mous, but instead of changing text color to background color I used expression to change text value `=IIF(InScope("RowGroup") = "True", Fields!Textboxvalue.Value, "")` - and it works as expected. 
Problem with background color change is that, if user unintendely select the text and makes it active, it become visible.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the Textbox in question, run F4 (to access to the properties chart at the right side of VS or SQL), select the HideDuplicates dropdown and Select the Data Set that you are using :)